# angular 1.5 $onChanges

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

So prior to the lifeCycle hook $onChanges I would use $scope.watch to track changes. After creating these watchers I would have to remove in order to keep my scope clean and avoid memory leaks. I was wondering if a similar manual clean up is required when using 1.5's $onChanges lifeCycle hook or since it is a lifeCycle hook it gets automatically taken care of when the component is destroyed.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

`$onChanges` is get deleted on destroy by itself. No need to manualy do it.

Answer (score 1):

Angular manages the life cycle of a component itself. From the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) itself,

> Angular creates it, renders it, creates and renders its children,
>   checks it when its data-bound properties change, and destroys it
>   before removing it from the DOM.

The lifecycle is pretty much the same in 1.5 so `$onChanges` lifecycle hook will be taken care automatically when the component is destroyed.